# Oracle SQL: How can I create a date table or date view using a date field in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I create a distinct list of dates for my date field in a separate sql view and then add calculated columns to that date field to extract the year, month, month name, and possibly the day.

So below is what I want my sql view to return

```
DATE        |  DAY  |  MONTH  |  MONTH_NAME  |  YEAR
------------------------------------------------
01-01-2020  |    01 |      01 | January      |  2020
03-01-2020  |    03 |      01 | January      |  2020
ETC....
```

Comment: Have you looked into using the `EXTRACT()` function?  Please include your current query if you have one.

Comment: I haven't got a query tbh was thinking if someone could advise me how to make one if I was going to create a date table this is how I would make it
SELECT DISTINCT datefield AS "DATE",
     extract(day from datefield) AS "DAY",
     extract(month from datefield) AS "MONTH".
     extract(year from datefield) AS "YEAR"
from table 

but I am new in sql so was looking for some advice on a better solution

Comment: also not sure how to get month name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use virtual columns:

```sql
CREATE TABLE calendar (
  dt         DATE PRIMARY KEY,
  day        NUMBER(2,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (EXTRACT(DAY FROM dt)),
  month      NUMBER(2,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dt)),
  month_name VARCHAR2(9)
             GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
               CAST(
                 TO_CHAR(dt, 'fmMonth', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
                 AS VARCHAR2(9)
               )
             ),
  year       NUMBER(4,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dt))
);
```

Then:

```sql
INSERT INTO calendar (dt)
SELECT DATE '2020-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-03' FROM DUAL;
```

The output of:

```sql
SELECT * FROM calendar;
```

Is:

> | DT | DAY | MONTH | MONTH_NAME | YEAR |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 | January | 2020 |
> | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | 3 | 1 | January | 2020 |

---

If you want to create a view of an existing table (for example, a view of the `calendar` table) then just use the same code in the `SELECT` of the view as in the virtual columns above:

```sql
CREATE VIEW calendar_view (dt, day, month, month_name, year) AS
SELECT dt,
       EXTRACT(DAY FROM dt),
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dt),
       TO_CHAR(dt, 'fmMonth', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'),
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dt)
FROM   calendar;
```

*Note: You can add the `CAST(... AS VARCHAR2(9))` if you want to restrict the size of the string but it is not necessary.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=331752cc39e60c8e0e518f50387cea3d)*

Comment: I can't create a table it has to be a view sorry I should have specified that in my question

Comment: thats fine thanks I understand how to change that to a view.

Comment: @Amar Updated to include a view.

Comment: also the datefield would I use the keyword distinct when creating a view

Comment: @Amar Only if you want to get rid of duplicate rows. We do not have your data so we cannot advise whether that is necessary or not.

Comment: yes I would like to remove the duplicates that's fine I'll do that thanks for your help